# CorePlot - graph reloadData is not working in 10.6.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, core-plot

I have a application in which i update the core plot graph dynamically. Basically as new data points are added i adjust the x axis range with new plot range if data points goes beyond the boundaries of graph. Graphs is working fine in OS X 10.7.3/10.7.4 and even on mountain lion 10.8 but on 10.6.8 it does not reload the graph. All methods are being called like numberFor plot and numberOfRecordsForPlot in 10.6.8 but does not work. If i adjust the window size a bit or maximize and minimize it shows the graph.

So seems to me that manual invocation of [graph reloadData] is not working on 10.6.8. Please suggest what to do.

Edit: I am using core plot 0.9 version and have also verified this issue with core plot 1.0 version using Plot Gallery sample and RealTime plot example
.

Regards,
MP

Comment: I cant check at the moment, but I will see what version I'm running tomorrow as I also dynamically add data points and manually reload the graph, and am able to do so without problems. Its also worth noting that to manually reload the graphs in that manner is not an elegant solution. Most sources that I read favored simply appending the data point to your NSMutableArray since as I understood it, that reloads/redraws your plot, but doesn't reload any unnecessary instances in the case that you have multiple ones.

Comment: Yes i do the same way by adding data to NSMutableArray and then invoke the [graph reloadData] method. Does you mean that just by adding data to NSMutableArray will reload the graph and does not require graph reloadData method to be invoked?

Comment: Well im running OSX 10.7.4 so I cant speak to the issues you are having on 10.6.8, is there a reason you specifically need to be running on that version?

Comment: The only reason is that app is on app store and we don't want to loose 10.6.8 customers as it does not uses any os specific apis so should work on all version. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ah, I understand, that makes some sense. Try to see if you can get into contact with the Core Plot guys, maybe they can figure out what might be breaking. Good Luck!

Comment: I have logged an issue there #445. Let's see now; for time being i did the workaround like 1) determined the OS version; 2) if it is 10.6.8 then i called [splitView adjustSubviews] that forces to redraw. I know it is bit hit to performance and memory but as not many people uses 10.6.8 so may work. Thanks.